# R cbind with grouped NA - Possible or not?

Tags: r, ggplot2, join

I want to make a ggsankey plot about our customer data regarding their travel destinations (regional) in different years.

I have the data regarding years and destinations formatted for the use in ggsankey. My main problem is how to join them in such a way that I keep the destinations over the years tied to the customer.

2020:

```
structure(list(Comp.ID = c(127716, 136562, 137968, 137968, 145464, 
156161), `2020` = c("Europa", "Amerika", "Azië", "Amerika", 
"Europa", "Amerika")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

2021:

```
structure(list(Comp.ID = c(127716, 136562, 136562, 136562, 137968, 
145464, 145464, 156161), `2021` = c("Europa", "Afrika", "Amerika", 
"Azië", "Amerika", "Europa", "Amerika", "Amerika")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

2022:

```
structure(list(Comp.ID = c(127716, 136562, 137968, 145464, 145464, 
145464, 156161), `2022` = c("Europa", "Amerika", "Azië", "Azië", 
"Amerika", "Europa", "Amerika")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried using `qpcR:::cbind.na(X2020, X2021, X2022 )`, but it just adds NAs to the shorter columns, which mixes up the connection between the IDs and the destinations.

What I need is some kind of grouped cbind.na, so that when `Comp.ID` 136562 has one row in 2020, three in 2021 and again one in 2022, the NAs get added for `Comp.ID` 136562 and not simply at the end of the column.

So these are the next steps (with the issue unresolved) for the plot:

```
DF <- qpcR:::cbind.na(X2020, X2021, X2022 )

DF2 <- DF %>% make_long(`2020`, `2021`, `2022`)


ggplot(DF2 ,
       aes(x = x, 
           next_x = next_x, 
           node = node, 
           next_node = next_node,
           fill = as.factor(node))) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(
    
    values = 
      
      c(
        
        "Europa" =  "#154273", 
        
        "Azië" ="#ca005d" , 
        
        "Amerika" ="#39870c", 
        
        "Afrika" = "#ffb612"
        
      )
    
    
  ) + 
    
  
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = .5) +
  theme_void() +
  
  theme(
    
    
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      
      colour = "#535353", 
      
      # face = "bold", 
      
      size= 15
      
    )
    
  )
```

Comment: so with the example you gave 136562, where would the NAs be? in 2020, 2021, or 2022?

Comment: What package is `make_long` from?

Comment: @JonSpring google says metan: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metan/versions/1.7.0/topics/make_long

Comment: `make_long` is part of `ggsankey: devtools::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")`

The NAs would get added in 2020 and 2022, which for this ID there is only one row in both columns, but three rows in the 2021 column.

But my main problem is the 'joining'. Once joined, generating the plot is not an issue.